# JQuery: validate all inputs within a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I need to apply same jquery validate rule to all the inputs with the `name="time"` of a table within a form. 
Html code:

```
<form id="thresholds">
    <table id="table" width="100%"> 
        <thead> 
        <tr> 
            <th width="35%">Service Name</th> 
            <th width="65%">Threshold</th>        
        </tr> 
        </thead> 
        <tbody> 
        <tr> 
            <td>Srv1</td> 
            <td><input id="Srv1" name="time"></input></td>        
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
            <td>Srv2</td> 
            <td><input id="Srv2" name="time"></input></td>  
        </tr>
        <tr> 
            <td>Srv3</td> 
            <td><input id="Srv3" name="time"></input></td>        
        </tr> 
        </tbody> 
    </table>                    
</form>
```

All the values in the inputs are expected to be valid timestamps. The method is

```
$.validator.addMethod("time", function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^(([0-1]?[0-9])|([2][0-3])):([0-5]?[0-9])(:([0-5]?[0-9]))?$/i.test(value);
}, "Please enter a valid time.");

$("#thresholds").validate({
    rules: {
        time: {
            required: true,
            time: true
        }
    }
});
```

This way the rule evaluates only the first input "Srv1".

I need it to affect Srv2 and Srv3 as well, i.e. all the

```
$('input[name="time"]').
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: So the issue is that your jquery selector only returns 1 DOM element?

Comment: jQuery Validate doesn't support multiple input's of type text with the same name.  You'd have to give them different names.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As I mentioned validating each input separately solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not in validator or selector. They are both correct. In further lines of the code I tried to enable/disable the Submit button relying on the form state:

```
$('input[name="time"]').on('keyup blur', function () { 
               if ($('#thresholds').valid()) {                   
                 $('#run').prop('disabled', false);                         
               } else {
                   $('#run').prop('disabled', true);                        
               }
           });
```

For some reason the condition $('#thresholds').valid() always returned TRUE even for invalid or empty input. The validation seemed to not work as well.

Validating each input individually solved the problem:

```
  $('input[name="time"]').on('keyup blur', function ()   { 
     if ($('#thresholds').validate().element($(this))) {                   
         $('#run').prop('disabled', false);                      
      } else {
         $('#run').prop('disabled', true);                        
      }
```

});